# How can I page through distinct filtered results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 
    f.id_service as f_id_service,
    f.id_city as f_id_city,
    f.name as f_name,
    f.address as f_address,
    f.business as f_business,
    f.web as f_web,
    f.phone as f_phone,
    f.id_firm as f_id_firm
FROM
    Firm f
        left join
    Price p ON p.id_service = f.id_service
        AND p.id_city = f.id_city
        AND p.id_firm = f.id_firm
WHERE
    f.blocked = '0'
        AND (f.name LIKE 'авто%'
        OR f.phone LIKE 'авто%')
        AND (f.phone != '' OR f.address != '')
        AND f.id_city = '73041'
        AND f.dogovor = '1'
ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

This query show TOP 20 rows with unique `f.name`

When me need select next 20 rows with unique f.name i use next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20
    f.id_service AS f_id_service,
    f.id_city AS f_id_city,
    f.name AS f_name,
    f.address AS f_address,
    f.business AS f_business,
    f.web AS f_web,
    f.phone AS f_phone,
    f.id_firm AS f_id_firm
FROM
    Firm f
        LEFT JOIN
    Price p ON p.id_service = f.id_service
        AND p.id_city = f.id_city
        AND p.id_firm = f.id_firm
WHERE
    f.name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20
            f.name
        FROM
            Firm f
        WHERE
            f.blocked = '0'
                AND (f.name LIKE '????%'
                OR f.phone LIKE '????%')
                AND (f.phone != '' OR f.address != '')
                AND f.id_city = '73041'
        ORDER BY f.name ASC)
        AND f.dogovor = '1'
        AND f.blocked = '0'
        AND (f.name LIKE '????%'
        OR f.phone LIKE '????%')
        AND (f.phone != '' OR f.address != '')
        AND f.id_city = '73041'
        AND f.dogovor = '1'
ORDER BY f.name ASC
```

But I see that in last query I query select rows with unique f.name from first query.

For example:

Result first query (select TOP 20 rows):
[image: first query]

Result second query (select NEXT TOP 20 rows):
[image: second query]

How you can see in second image second query have rows from first image(result first query).

Tell me please where error and how write right ?

Comment: hey change the alias of Firm table in sub query and then try

Comment: OFFSET (in MySQL - LIMIT) there was only in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Devart didn't realize that. thanks for the information. deleted since my solution is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 
    f.id_service AS f_id_service, 
    f.id_city AS f_id_city, 
    f.name AS f_name, 
    f.[address] AS f_address, 
    f.business AS f_business, 
    f.web AS f_web, 
    f.phone AS f_phone, 
    f.id_firm AS f_id_firm 
FROM dbo.Firm f
WHERE f.blocked = '0' 
    AND (f.name LIKE 'авто%' OR f.phone LIKE 'авто%') 
    AND f.phone + f.[address] != ''
    AND f.id_city='73041' 
    AND f.dogovor='1' 
ORDER BY f.name


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        f.id_service AS f_id_service, 
        f.id_city AS f_id_city, 
        f.name AS f_name, 
        f.[address] AS f_address, 
        f.business AS f_business, 
        f.web AS f_web, 
        f.phone AS f_phone, 
        f.id_firm AS f_id_firm,
        row_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.name)
    FROM dbo.Firm f
    WHERE f.blocked = '0' 
        AND (f.name LIKE 'авто%' OR f.phone LIKE 'авто%') 
        AND f.phone + f.[address] != ''
        AND f.id_city='73041' 
        AND f.dogovor='1' 
) d
WHERE d.row_id BETWEEN 21 AND 40
```

Comment: And also `LEFT JOIN Price p` not needed.

Answer (score 0):

which collation are you using? perhaps that is why the strings are not being excluded by your 
'where f.name not in' clause

As you are selecting what seems to be an ID for the table, you can do without the 'Distinct', this would allow you to filter out the top 20 records by ID.

WHERE 
f.id_service NOT IN (
SELECT TOP 20 f.id_service FROM Firm f WHERE f.blocked='0' ...

Comment: no, i cannt use id, becose hi not exist (id_serveice not use)

Comment: I think Ted's suggestion is the first thing to check - add 'dogovor = 1' to the not in clause and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it might be a language barrier but let's be clear, your fist query doesn't display unique f.name but unique combinations of all columns.

Also, using TOP and DISTINCT in such manner is a very bad idea. There is no way to be sure that you will be getting the same results every single time.

Finally your NOT IN clause is missing `AND f.dogovor='1'`